# How to check if time in day is between two times?

Tags: java, android, time, calendar, jodatime

In my app I create an object that represents a high school class.  This object holds 2 Calendar objects that represents the class's start and stop time each day.  When a user creates an assignment I want to check if the current time is between the two times of any of the classes.  If it is I know that the assignment was created during that class.  Here is my current code that does not work because .getTime() returns a date that includes month, and day, while I would just like to compare hours, and minutes.  SO how can I trim the returned dates to just include the time in day?  Would this be easier with joda-time, and if so what classes should be used?

```
    public void checkTimeFrame() {
    time = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    ArrayList<SchoolClass> mList = mClassList;

    // Changes index if assignment falls under time frame of class
    for (int a = 0; a < mList.size(); a++) {
        if (mList.get(a).getStartTime() != null && mList.get(a).getEndTime() != null &&
                time.after(mList.get(a).getStartTime().getTime()) && time.before(mList.get(a)
                .getEndTime().getTime())) {
            index = a;
            updateClassEditText();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Calendar.get()`, as mentioned in another answer. To compare minutes, though, you should use [`Calendar.MINUTE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#MINUTE), too:

```
int minutes_in_day = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60 + time.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Then, you can just compare the minutes within the day of the current time with that of the start and end times. This will, of course, only work when the times are in the same day.

Comment: The field HOUR_OF_DAY is a static constant `public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY 11`

Answer (score 2):

JDK 8 Date-Time APIs are a good approach to solving these kinds of issues. Instead of Calendar , use LocalTime to store the start and end time of the class.

```
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalTime start = mList.get(a).getStartTime();
LocalTime end = mList.get(a).getEndTime();
if(now.isAfter(start) && now.isBefore(end)){
    //do something
}
```

For Android, you can use The [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project which adapts the java.time APIs for Android.

Comment: Thanks! After trying a lot of solutions with `Calendar` etc. that takes about 10-15 lines of code and scored about 200 votes and didn't work for me, this solves my issue easily, thanks!

Comment: @Daria glad to know that my answer helped.

Answer (score 0):

The Calendar class has a `get` method where you can `get` different fields

e.g.

```
int hr = time.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I will here only provide the Joda-Time-related answer you asked for. Joda-Time has the advantage to offer a dedicated type for the clock time, namely [LocalTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html). The old `java.util.Calendar`-stuff does not offer this advantage hence your difficulties.

First you convert an instance of `java.util.Date` like follows:

```
Date time = ...;
DateTime dt = new DateTime(time, DateTimeZone.getDefault());
LocalTime lt = dt.toLocalTime();
```

Note that the conversion is always timezone dependent. Then you can compare two `LocalTime` instances using the inherited methods `isAfter(...)` or `isBefore(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        Date date1 = sdf.parse(given time);
        Date date2 = sdf.parse("08:00 AM");
        Date date3 = sdf.parse("06:00 PM");

        if((date1.after(date2))&&(date1.before(date3))||date1.equals(date2) ||date1.equals(date3) ) {

        } 
    } catch (ParseException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```