# Can someone help me creating Java code that checks the time and sets a Boolean to false when it is between certain hours of the day

Tags: java, time, java-time

Basically as the title says I am trying to make a boolean change to false whenever it is between certain hours of the day. I am attempting this in java.

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.time.Clock;
import java.time.Duration;

public class timeLock {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean lock = false;
        Duration myTimeOffset = Duration.ofHours(3);
        Clock OD = Clock.systemUTC();
        Clock OrderTime = Clock.offset(OD, myTimeOffset);
        System.out.println(OrderTime.instant());
    }
}
```

Here is all the code I have and as of right now the problem I run into is the format of the clock doesn't work for if statments. So really my goal is just to find a way to get it formated into something readable by if statements so that the boolean will change to true.

Comment: Have you looked at any of the Clock or Duration documentation ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Did you search? This has been asked and answered more than once before. Does this answer your question? [How to check if time in day is between two times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112299/how-to-check-if-time-in-day-is-between-two-times) Please learn that you are supposed to search before posting a question here.

Comment: I think you neither need the `Duration`, the `Clock` nor the `Instant` class for this. And you definitely should not use `DateFormat` (an old and troublesome class). You do want to use `LocalTime`. See the answer..

Answer (score 1):

You've stated you want to know if the current time is between two hours of the day.  The following will set the variable `isInTimeRange` to true if it is between 6 AM and 4 PM local time, or false otherwise:

```java
LocalTime start = LocalTime.parse("06:00:00");
LocalTime end = LocalTime.parse("16:00:00");
LocalTime now = LocalTime.now();
boolean isInTimeRange = start.isBefore(now) && now.isBefore(end);
```

This utilizes the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class, which represents a time without a time zone.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, the [`java.time.LocalDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) class may be of help. With it you are able to fetch the current hour of the day on the user's computer using [`LocalDateTime.now().getHour()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#getHour--). The method returns the hour in the form of an int with 0 being 12am and 23 being 11pm. I've included some sample code below to help you better understand how you could use this to solve your problem

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Main {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        int[] hourRange = {10, 14}; // Hour range 10am to 2pm
        
        // If low range is above high range then swap them
        if (hourRange[1] < hourRange[0]) {
            int tmp = hourRange[0];
            hourRange[0] = hourRange[1];
            hourRange[1] = tmp;
        }
        
        int currentHour = LocalDateTime.now().getHour(); // Get the current hour in 24 hour time (https://www.onlineconversion.com/date_12-24_hour.htm)
        boolean lock = currentHour > hourRange[0] && currentHour < hourRange[1]; // Check if it's inside of the range. If it is then the bool will be true, otherwise false
        System.out.println(lock);
        
    }

}
```

Many would also request that you follow the [proper naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) for the reason that it makes your code easier to read and understand.